# Create Android application which uses "guardianproject/openssl-android" libraries(.so)

Tags: android, openssl

I have built the `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so` from this (https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android) project. Then I created a new android project and added the new libs to the jni/ folder.

Which additional header files do I need to add to the project to use openSSL functions? If I add the `include/openssl/`folder from guardianproject (which consist of header files) it doesn't compile, is there are some config file in guardianproject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[openssl-android](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android) just provides the native openssl libraries **libcrypto.so** and **libssl.so**, it does not provide any Java implementation.  If you want to use this openssl in native code, you would add the folder **relative/path/to/include/openssl/** to `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` in your **Android.mk**.  You probably want to add **openssl-android**  as a git submodule to your project.